# How Can I use Criteria with relational mapped objects?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have mapped my relational bbdd tables to Java Objects.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{

// Another attributes...
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private UserAccount userAccount;

// Getters and setters...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable{

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
        parameters =
        @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int user_id;
// Another attributes...

// Getters and setters...

}
```

I have one Criterion like this.

```
Criterion crit = Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.like("userAccount.email", email),
                Restrictions.like("userAccount.password", MD5.crypt(password)));
```

But I get this error.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: User of: com.mypackage.entity.User
```

How can I do access to UserAccount.email from User through Criteria?

Comment: Show the full criteria creation code from which you are getting your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new criteria for each join:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class)
        .createCriteria("userAccount").add(Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.like("email", email),
                Restrictions.like("password", MD5.crypt(password)));d
```

Comment: Hi Amin, is good your question, only I had to delete userAccount inside Restrictions.like.

Comment: But now I have another doubt, If i would use one User attribute with another useraccount attribute in same Criteria, How can I do?

Comment: Do it before creating the joined Criteria